# Emacs as database client?

Tags: sql

Linux Mint 20.2

Emacs 27.2

In my work I use the next DBs:

- PostgreSQL
- SQLite
- MySQL
- Oracle
- MS SQlServer

So I need different database client to work with it.
It's not very convenient.

So, the question is:
Is it possible to use Emacs as database client to work with DBs?

I need to do:

- Executing SQL queries (`select, update, dalete` and so on)
- Export result of query to file (`csv, txt`)
- Backup DB

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what wasn't satisfactory with that? Have you tried `sql-mode`, for instance?

Comment: Or the Org babel evaluator `ob-sql`? Or use your favorite python editing environment to write your queries in python and use python's sql facilities to deal with the various databases? Or perl if you prefer that to python? Or search for `emacs and sql` on the web and you'll find about 3 million results :-)